# Cannot Install msecli on Linux

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I want to use some options provided by msecli (a command line interface to manage SSDs) such as formatting. I am working on Linux Mint 18.3. Based on the information provided on documents in [Micron Storage Executive and msecli page](https://www.micron.com/products/solid-state-drives/storage-executive-software), I downloaded the msecli for Linux. However, after executing it, some par2 files are generated which I don't know what to do with them and msecli is not installed yet. It seems that documents are not matched with the downloaded msecli.

The executive file is named msecli_Linux.run and after running it the .par2 files are created which are shown in this image. I don't know what to do in the further steps. When I type the command `msecli` or `./msecli`. I get the error `msecli: command not found`.

How can I install msecli, successfully?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and post the actual error messages in full.

Comment: Try to make it executable with `chmod +x ./msecli_Linux.run` command, then execute in a terminal.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks it is solved. Are you going to post the solution yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Problem: When I type the command `msecli` or `./msecli`. I get the error `msecli: command not found`.
- Solution: That's because files are not executable by default. Try to make it executable with `chmod +x ./msecli_Linux.run` command, then execute in a terminal.